# Liferay user deactivation using LDAPImportMessageListener

Tags: active-directory, ldap, liferay, liferay-6

I have a liferay instance instance running on *websphere7.0, RHEL 5* which is connected to my organization's Active Directory.

I have a requirement where the user in liferay database should get **automatically deactivated** when that user is **deleted from the AD**.
The basic liferay functionality is that if a user is deleted from the AD, that user doesn't get deleted or deactivated in liferay. The only thing we can control from the control panel is that whether that deleted user(from AD) can log into the portal or not.

I searched and found that we can LDAPImportMessageListener class to customize the basic liferay behavior. But i am sure how to do that.

Please help.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete / Deactivate user in Liferay is not implement OOB when user deleted from AD, You would need to add your implementation by **extending PortalLDAPImporterImpl.java**

Comment: Can you suggest a way to extend **PortalLDAPImporterImpl.java** ? Do i need to create an ext ?

Comment: Yes you would need to create ext through plugin sdk - this link will help you http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10755176